# Can Flutter's Firestore cache manage several FirestoreListView with the exact same query without requesting the data several times?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that has this Firestore structure:

**Collection "groups"**

```yaml
title: "Group's title"
members:
  - "user_id_1"
  - "user_id_2"
posts: SubCollection
```

**Group's sub-collection "posts"**

```yaml
text: "user's text"
image: "image_url"
author: "author_id"
```

I have a Flutter app that needs to sync between users in near real-time and has different pages that list the groups:

**The page "Groups"**

This page lists the groups the user belongs to.

The list is built with:

- A query that filters the "groups" collection, finding all the groups with the current user in the list of members. (I may create a list of groups in the user data if this is more efficient)
- A FirestoreListView widget that uses this query to create ListTile for each group. A tap on the ListTile opens the group's dedicated page with the posts.

**The page "Create a post"***

When opened outside of the context of a group, the page "create a post" contains a selector with all the groups of the user, so that the user can choose a group the post belongs to.

The list in the selector is also generated with a query that finds all groups with the current user in the members and a F`irestoreListView` widget with a different `ListTitle` widget.

**The question**

My first move was to create a centralized list of groups in the state. Then I realized that asking exactly the same data at different interface points shall leverage the Firestore cache. So it seems to me that it is not an issue to use 2 `FirestoreListView` as long as the query is exactly the same. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you have active two listeners to the exact same query/collection, the data will be retrieved from the server only once. If that is not the behavior you're observing, please edit your question to show a [minimal/standalone repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, if you have multiple listeners who are listening to the exact query, then you'll be billed for reading the documents only once. Basically, only the first listener will produce reads. This means that all the other queries will be fulfilled since the data is already in the cache. Remember that documents read from the cache are **not** billed as reads.

Comment: Hey Xiiryo. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?